# Xamarin use KEYSTORE in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, xamarin

I recently finished rewriting an app from Xamarin to Flutter. I only need the launch in the AppStore. Is there a way to use the old signature (Xamarin) for the new version (flutter)?

Comment: Presumably Flutter uses the same Android key signing tools that Xamarin does.  You just need to figure out where the keystore file is located

Comment: Could you explain a little more about it please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=windows

Comment: If I have not read correctly, the website you sent explains how to get the keystore of the Xamarin project, or am I wrong? (Just to be more specific, I already have the keystore, I just need to know how to use it in my flutter project)

Comment: I've never used Flutter but 10s of searching led me to https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app